# Get values from Data-Driven key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dict like below with hundreds of "assets". I would like to get the key="href" and print the url but because all "assets" are in a list and the first key of "assets" is changing I havent found a way to get there. Thanks for helping!

```py
d = {"features": [

    {
        "assets": {
            "swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24_2056_5728.dxf.zip": {
                "checksum:multihash":
                    "1220A94A04BD19E190139FAD49E6174DE82987221F7330DDEB7F6943AEAC3D7C4C78",
                "created": "2021-02-10T17:51:31.618859Z",
                "href":
                    "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24_2056_5728.dxf.zip",
                "proj:epsg": 2056,
                "type": "application/x.dxf+zip",
                "updated": "2021-02-10T17:51:31.618877Z"
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "assets": {
            "swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42_2056_5728.dxf.zip": {
                "checksum:multihash":
                    "1220EA3AFCCDE8648CB60CDF17AF679458233DE2E6052CBBB91F058CBCA651191F6D",
                "created": "2021-02-10T17:51:33.722985Z",
                "href":
                    "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42_2056_5728.dxf.zip",
                "proj:epsg": 2056,
                "type": "application/x.dxf+zip",
                "updated": "2021-02-10T17:51:33.723005Z"}
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: You say you have this `dict`, and you need access to those attributes, but how, where, why? Can you share some code of what you actually tried? Do you just want a list of all tuples of key and url from the dicts in the list? And is the "key" the file name key in "assets"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to coding. I experimented with jmespath, glom and regex but nothing really worked for me. Yes I want a list of all urls for automated download of files and I don't care how :-) When printing the "assets" I get the whole block as 1 value and I cant get any deeper because of the usually unkonwn key = "swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1....." I found some workaround with other data where I put the url together with strings but thats not ideal.

Comment: urls = re.findall("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+", swisstopo_data) can't filter the end of the url correctly, in the original document there are dozens of urls, but I only need the one with the .dxf suffix

Comment: assets = jmespath.search("features[*].assets", swisstopo_data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
output_list = []
for data_dict in d['features']:
    for key, value_dict in data_dict['assets'].items():
        output_list.append(value_dict['href'])

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
['https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24_2056_5728.dxf.zip', 'https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42_2056_5728.dxf.zip']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary in your example is assigned to a variable called `d`, this works:

```
result = [(next(iter(x['assets'])), x['assets'][next(iter(x['assets']))]['href']) for x in d['features']]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24_2056_5728.dxf.zip', 'https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-24_2056_5728.dxf.zip'), ('swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42_2056_5728.dxf.zip', 'https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.swissbuildings3d_2/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42/swissbuildings3d_2_2018-07_1064-42_2056_5728.dxf.zip')]
```

If what you shared wasn't in fact a dictionary, but a .json file, this is how to get it all the same:

```
import json

with open('mydata.json') as f:
    d = load.loads(f.read())
```